# Streaming mpeg-ts files with multiple subtitle tracks with vlc

Tags: vlc

I would like to stream a ts encoded file with vlc. The file has multiple audio tracks and multiple subtitle tracks.

Is it possible to stream it so that in the player on the receiving end the user can select the audio track and the subtitle track, and if it is, how do I do it?

The stream is set up via a vlm script that looks like this:

```
new foobar vod enabled
setup foobar input /path/to/foobar.ts
```

With this setup, I have only been able to see 1 audio track and no subtitle track on the receiving end.

Answer (score 1):

you don´t need VLM for this. 
In windows cmd just type vlc(make sure to build the correct path or execute it from de VLC directory) input_to_stream :sout=#Module1{option1={option 1.1}}:Module 2....:sout-all this is the key. The receiver may select from the UI the program and the track the want to watch

Answer (score 1):

vlc -H |grep "--sout-all"

```
  --sout-all, --no-sout-all  Enable streaming of all ES (default disabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

I too effectively wanted to re-transmit a TV recorded MPEG2-TS with its DVB subtitles. After three long hard days, I found a way to do this with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html).

VLC has a GUI to set up a streaming server, but of course can also be used at the command line.  VLM (included with VLC) can serve multiple files simultaneously, or you can just use VLC to stream a single file for single use.  I finally found the command that worked for me was:

```
cvlc -v /host/home/user/file.ts --sout-all --no-ts-split-es --sout "#duplicate{dst=udp{dst=MachineName:1234}}"
```

I'm sharing this in the hope that I'll save some others the time it took me to find the all important '**--no-ts-split-es**' option!